# Add javascript action to all links on a webpage

Tags: javascript, joomla

Good morning, I would like to know if is possible add automaticalliy a javascript action to all links (or classes) on a webpage, for example I wanna add the following javascript action:  "PlayFlashSound();", so the links on my web page should be:

```
<a onmouseover="PlayFlashSound();" href="#">Link Text</a>"
```

The problem adding manually the javascript action is that I'm using Joomla, and I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery you could do it like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').click(function() {

        PlayFlashSound();

        return false

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could easily be accomplished using jQuery:

```
$('a').mouseover(function()
{
    PlayFlashSound();
});
```

[Example available here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fzsVf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume since one of this question tags is "joomla" the author would like to accomplish what's needed using Mootool that is included into Joomla CMS. The code could be, for instance, like this one:

window.addEvent("domready",
function() {

```
$$('a').each(function(item, index) {

    item.addEvent('click', PlayFlashSound);
});
```

})

Keep in mind that if you wish to block the default actions of those links the PlayFlashSound function must return "false";